# Optimization Modeling over time

Tags: optimization

Does anyone have any suggestions on where I can learn optimization modeling with multiple time periods, i.e. multiple purchase points (monthly over two years).

An example would be multiple rent-to-own contracts that have purchase price decreases at 12-month increments. So with a limited amount of capital for the year, what is the most efficient purchasing strategy that minimizes costs over two years?

Thanks,

Comment: Many practical models have variables with a time index, e.g. `x[i,t]` where i=item, t=time (for instance month). In financial models you need to worry about discount ratios, interest etc. I don't think there is a single good reference for this, but it makes sense to look at research papers related to your application area.

Comment: Thanks, I will do little research and hopefully find a paper that is similar to my needs